# x86: Combination of conditions, jumps and labels

Tags: assembly, x86, reverse-engineering, disassembly

I got stuck in interpretation of the following code. To make it simple, I have replaced some numbers read from data segment with direct numbers:

```
L1:

    fld qword ptr [Data1]
    fcomp 1.0

    fnstsw ax
    test ah, 01h
    jz L2

    fld qword ptr [Data2]

    jmp L3


L2:

    cmp word ptr [Data3], 0001h
    jnz L4 

    fld qword ptr [Data4]

L3:

    fstp qword ptr [esp+10h]

L4:

    fld qword ptr [Data5]
    fcomp 1.0

    fnstsw ax
    test ah, 01h
    jz L5

    mov qword ptr [Data6], 43.0

L5:

    fld qword ptr [Data7]
    fcomp 1.0

    fnstsw ax
    test ah, 01h
    jz L6
    mov qword ptr [Data7], 53.2

L6:
```

This is my interpretation from this code:

```
double Data1
double Data2
int Data3
double Data4
double Data5
double Data6
double Data7


if Data1<=1.0 || Data3==1

    if Data1<=1.0
        *(esp+10h)= Data4;
    else
        *(esp+10h)= Data2;
    end

end

if Data5<=1.0
    Data6=43.0;
end

if Data7 <= 1.0
    Data7=53.2;
end
```

I have two concerns:

- Is my interpreted code correct?
- In the range between `L1` to `L4` there are two comparisons but how come in my high level code, I have 3 comparisons and I cannot reduce it to two comparisons? The original code has been in a high/mid level code. I have no information about the original code language or the compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got some conditions wrong. After `fcom` the `C0` flag (eventually bit #0 in `AH`) is set if `st0` is strictly less than the operand (or the comparison is unordered).

```
if Data1 < 1.0
    *(esp+10h)= Data2;
else if Data3 == 1
    *(esp+10h)= Data4;
end

if Data5 < 1.0
    Data6=43.0;
end

if Data7 < 1.0
    Data7=53.2;
end
```